# How do I add some data to a JSON file?

Tags: node.js, json

I know this has probably been asked here somewhere, but I've been looking for a couple hours now and thought I'd just post myself.

I'm trying to add some data, (an object), to a .json, but each time I add more data it gets weirder and weirder... Here is my code

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = [(fs.readFileSync('serverSettings.json').toString())];

data.push({
    "server": 'foo',
    "channel": 'bar'
});

fs.writeFileSync('serverSettings.json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

But here is what gets uploaded to the .json, after adding the data like 4 times:

```
["[\"[\\\"[\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\",{\\\\\\\"server\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"foo\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"channel\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"bar\\\\\\\"}]\\\",{\\\"server\\\":\\\"foo\\\",\\\"channel\\\":\\\"bar\\\"}]\",{\"server\":\"foo\",\"channel\":\"bar\"}]",{"server":"foo","channel":"bar"}]
```

I know this has probably been asked here before, but if you could just please give me some code that works that'd be awesome, since I've been struggling with this for wayyy longer than necessary, ty

============ANSWER============
I finally figured it out....

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = [(fs.readFileSync('serverSettings.json').toString())];

data = JSON.parse(data)

data.push({
    "server": 'foo',
    "channel": 'bar'
});

fs.writeFileSync('serverSettings.json', (JSON.stringify(data)));
```

This is what I had to do, BUT, I also had to put a [] in the .json by default, or it wouldn't be able to push... ty for the help peoples, and ty for not flaming me lol

Comment: Why are you stringify  the Json?

Comment: bc if i dont it dies

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It can be used to persist the data or to transfer it to another computer. In order to manipulate the data represented as JSON you have to parse it back into a data structure  equivalent to the one used to create the JSON. Read about [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and use it with the data you read from file.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It can be used to persist the data or to transfer it to another computer. In order to manipulate the data represented as JSON you have to parse it back into a data structure  equivalent to the one used to create the JSON.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = 'serverSettings.json';

let settings = {};
try {
  // Read the settings persisted in the JSON file...
  const rawData = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');

  // ... and parse the data back into an object
  settings = JSON.parse(rawData);
} catch (err) {
  // Something wrong happened, either the file does not exist, or it cannot be read
  // or its content is not valid JSON

  // Initialize/reset the settings object with some defaults
  settings = {
    // ... put some defaults here
  };
}

// The settings were loaded, update them
settings.server = 'foo';
settings.channel = 'bar';

// Save the settings back into the file
fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(settings), { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Read about [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in the JavaScript documentation.

Comment: youre the actual mvp, tysm

Answer (score 0):

```
# the id(Var) method gives the memory adress of an object the identifier
#                 'Var' points to. 
L1 = ["1"]
L2 = L1
assert L2 is L1       # no assertion error as it is true
print(f'{id(L1)=}, {id(L2)=}') # L1, L2 point to same object in memory
assert id(L1) == id(L2)
print(f'{id(L1[0])=}, {id("1")=}')
L2[0] = "2"     
assert L1[0] == L2[0] # no assertion error as it is true
print(f'{id(L1)=}, {id(L2)=}') # L1, L2 point to same object in memory
assert id(L1) == id(L2)
print(f'{id(L1[0])=}, {id("1")=}')
print(f'{L1=}, {L2=}') # both identifier point to same list object
L2 = ["2"]     
print(f'{id(L1)=}, {id(L2)=}') # L1, L2 DON'T point to same object
assert id(L1) != id(L2) 


# An attempt to explain the big difference between immutable strings 
# and mutable lists ( answering: Why this and not other output? )

env = '!_a'   # env -> identifier for the string object            '!_a'
#         assignment step-1: evaluation of '!_a' creates in memory '!_a'
#         assignment step-2: env becomes a 'pointer' to            '!_a'
print(env)    # print will output what env 'points' to, i.e.       '!_a' 
tempenv = env # tempenv -> another identifier pointing to          '!_a'
tempenv = tempenv[1:] # tempenv will now 'point' to                 '_a'
#         assignment step-1: evaluation of tempenv[1:] creates      '_a'
#         assignment step-2: tempenv becomes 'pointer' to           '_a'
print(env)    # print will output what env 'points' to, i.e.       '!_a'
print(tempenv)# print will output what tempenv 'points' to, i.e.    '_a'
# Both the string objects '!_a' and '_a' exist in memory because there
# are identifier pointing to them. 
"""
output:
!_a
!_a 
_a
# ======================================================================
List object is a container with pointers to another objects and will 
not behave like the string object did:
"""
print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
env = ['!_a'] # env -> will point to a list object               ['!_a'] 
#         assignment step-1: evaluation of '!_a' creates in memory '!_a'
#         assignment step-2: evaluation of [] creates in memory a list []
#         assignment step-3: evaluation of ['!_a'] sets the pointer to
#             first element in  the new created list pointing to  '!_a'  
#         assignment step-4: env becomes a 'pointer' to the list object
print(env) # print will output what env 'points' to, i.e.        ['!_a']
tempenv = env # tempenv will point to what env points too i.e.   ['!_a']
#         assignment step-1: evaluation of env gives             ['!_a']
#         assignment step-2: tempenv is now another 'pointer' to ['!_a']
#             both env and tempenv point to same memory object   ['!_a']
#             if the memory object ['!_a'] will change both the  
#             tempenv and env will 'point' to the changed list object
tempenv[0] = tempenv[0][1:] # the list object ['!_a'] will be modified 
#         assignment step-0: evaluation of tempenv gives object ['!_a']
#         assignment step-1: evaluation of tempenv[0] leads to    '!_a'
#         assignment step-2: evaluation of '!_a'[1:] creates a new '_a'
#         assignment step-3: evaluation of tempenv[0] gives the 
#             'pointer' to the first element in the list object  
#         assignment step-4: the pointer from step-3 of the list object
#             will now point to the '_a' created in step-2 
#         the list object ['!_a'] was changed and is now         ['_a']
#         both env and tempenv point to the same list object     ['_a']
print(env) # print will output what env     'points' to, i.e.    ['_a']
print(tempenv) #   will output what tempenv 'points' to, i.e.    ['_a']
"""
output:
['!_a']
['_a']
['_a']

Why has it happened is explained above. What leaves only the question
    'what happened to '!_a' and ['!_a'] ? 
"""
# Now there exist only a list object ['_a'] and the string object '_a'.
# There is only one list object, but two identifier pointing to it. 
# The list object was changed, so ['!_a'] mutated to ['_a']. 
# The string '!_a' doesn't eventually exist at all as there are no 
# identifier pointing to it, so cleaning up memory will definitely 
# delete it at some point.
```